# C# EF Se actualizan todos los registros cuando solo deberia ser uno

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo la siguiente tabla, con los siguientes valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar esta tabla uso el siguiente query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Casiller
WHERE cod_parte ='3650.3.75'
```

En `C#` tengo una función donde utilizo `EF` para tratar de hacer una resta de la cantidad DONDE el `rollo` sea igual a X y el `cod_parte` sea igual a Y (un `AND` así):

```
public string SetSaldoNuevo(string materialX, string rolloX, decimal saldo)
        {
            try
            {
                //obtengo saldo 15300 de saldo por ejemplo 
                decimal SaldoX = SaldoXRollo(rolloX);

                using (var ctx=new ModelContextSIKOR())
                {
                    //aca resto el saldo los 15300 por 10000 que me deberia dar 5300
                    decimal saldoNuevo = SaldoX - saldo;
                    var entidad = ctx.Casiller.Where(x => x.cod_parte == materialX && x.rollo == rolloX)
                                              .FirstOrDefault();
                    entidad.cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(saldoNuevo);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
                return "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Acá estoy obteniendo un único rollo como debería ser :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me esta seteando el valor de 5300 a todos los rollos de la primera imagen, si estoy utilizando correctamente el && CON SU respectivos datos, por que me da el mismo valor para todos?, que estoy omitiendo? gracias.

Comment: Aparentemente la relación entre `cod_parte` y `rollo` identifican de manera única al registro, por lo tanto, sólo debería haber una fila actualizada. Intenta ver si ese es el caso. Intenta ver el conteo de las filas cambiadas con `var lineasAfectadas = ctx.SaveChanges();`. Si el conteo es igual a 1, entonces, tu problema no está en esa sección de código. De ser así, estás actualizando los registros dentro de un ciclo?

Comment: No pongas link de la imagen puedes insertarla directamente